# Hide un-classed element, and show it's sibling?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've got some HTML code I can't modify. I don't want to use JS/jQuery to do this, would like to get it done with cross-browser friendly CSS.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
        <a href-"#">Item One</a> |
    </li>
     <li class="item">
        <a href-"#">Item Two</a> |
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href-"#">Item Three</a> |
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's got those stupid pipes in there to break up the list. I Want to hide those, and show the `<a>` elements. I don't just want to make the text color the same as the background either. I'd like an equivalent of `display: none;`

Comment: Almost impossible to remove the pipes as they aren't selectable with CSS AFAIK

Comment: @jbenjohnson - I don't believe you can `none` a parent and `block` a child, as the parent controls the display mode for the child as well, so it all remains hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `font-size` of the `li` to 0 and give it a transparent `color`, then set those properties back to normal on the `a`:

```css
li.item {
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
}

li.item a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
}
```

This makes the `li` text invisible and have no size whatsoever, but keeps the `a` element styled as it should.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2TDHa/).

*Note that I've used transparency here as (as far as I recall) Safari has a problem with fully hiding the font when its size is set to 0.*

Comment: I don't need the bullets. It's a simple `[ Item 1 ][ Item 2]` horizontal menu. I think this may be the best way around it, didn't think of font-size, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
.item {
    color: transparent;
}

.item a {
    color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wtVz2/).

This means that the text of the `li` is invisible/transparent (though it can still be selected), but the text colour of the `a` element is made visible.

Comment: I've tried this, and don't want to simply change the color. I want it to act like it's not there.